# Sum every 11 rows excel

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I have a table with 2600+ rows, related to towns in my region and their population; each town has 11 rows, one for each age class (0-9, 10-19, and so on). 
I need to get the sum of the population of each town; of course I can do it manually but it's a never ending job; I wonder if there's some kind of command that tells excel to do the sum every 11 rows and do it for all the towns.
I think it's a kind of loop but I have no idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be reduced by using [the SUMIF function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#SUMIF). The question then becomes how to apply this to your dataset.

Assuming one of the columns in your 2600+ rows contains the town name (or another unique identifier), and you have a list of towns (or other unique identifier), the below method can be used.

[image: Excel example]

The formula in E2 is `=SUMIF(A:A,D2,C:C)`, and in E3 `=SUMIF(A:A,D3,C:C)`. A to C is the list of all data, D is a list of towns.

Answer (score 1):

For a VBA solution, you should be able to use a step in the loop.
So if you wish to step by 11 rows at a time.

```
Public Sub IterateRows()

Dim rData As Range, rPtr As Range
Dim dSum As Double
Dim i As long

Set rData = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000")
For i = 1 To rData.Rows.Count Step 11
    Set rPtr = rData(1).Resize(11).Offset(i - 1)
    dSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rPtr)
Next

End Sub
```

If you want a worksheet function solution, you will probably have to use the MOD operator and check for when the value is zero..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any reference columns? As in...say for example Column A has the Town Name, and Column B has the Age Class, and Column C has the values.

Going down the rows Column A will have repeating town names, yes?

Like this:

```
Town - Age Class - Pop
Wherever - 0-9 - 1000
Wherever - 10-19 - 2000
Wheverer - 20-29 - 2500
```

Assuming you have maintained the data structure (NO GAPS) a possible solution in Column D (or whatever column just make sure you change the references) could be (putting this in D2 and dragging it down the length of your sheet):

```
=IF(A1<>A2,SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(A2)&":C"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A:A=A2)*(ROW(A:A)))))),D1)
```

This works if you have any amount of rows per town, so long as you SORT by town name so the same names are next to each other in the list and there are no gaps.

[image: test data]

In the above test data set I subtracted 250 from each Values count per Town going down (each class has 250 less than the previous city) just to show some variation in the output...you can see each city has 2750 (250 * 11) less pop than the previous.

Basically it builds an array with a starting position of "not the town above" in the first row it encounters a new town name to an ending position of "last (max) position of new town in same list" so that is how it doesn't matter how many rows you have per town. From 1 to memory limit basically, I think. :)

ALTHOUGH, this also works:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)
```

Yep. Not kidding just drag that down Column D...

Comment: with the first method excel gives me an error, as well as libreoffice calc; the second method works smoothly in excel, while in libreoffice calc doesn't. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this manual method which is not a never ending job; i.e.:

[image]

- in `E11` put your formula as `=SUM(C1:C11)`
- copy range `E1:E11`
- select range `E12:E2600` and paste special function

Comment: also this one works; and, so far, it's the easiest solution! I wasn't aware of this kind of paste special!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following structure

[image]

This is a very easy task using a **pivot table**.

For LibreOffice Calc:

1. Just select the complete data area including the column headers (in my example: `A1:C13`);
2. Menu `Data` -> `Pivot Table`;
3. `Current selection`;
4. Following settings for Pivot table:
   [image]
   (drag the `Town` field into the `Row Fiels` area, and the `Count` field into the `Data fields` area. LO Calc will offer to calculate the Sum of the count entries by default).
5. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> - the resulting pivot table will look like this:

   [image]

This solution has the advantage that the source data area hasn't to be sorted by town, and it doesn't matter if some towns don't have nine value rows each. Additionally, you don't need any formulas.

EDIT:

You can work with the contents of the pivot table the same way as with calculated results. For example, you could use the pivot table values to calculate the sum for some of the towns (in my example, calculate the sum for town B and C based on the pivot table values `B3` and `B4` respectively):

[image]

Comment: I've considered a pivot table but I need these sums to do other calculations, so the pivot doesn't fit for my case; thanks!

Comment: @Ale: you can use the pivot table values to do any further calculations, too (at least in LO Calc - didn't test it in excel...). They are normal sheet contents the same way as formula / function results. I've added an example...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the MOD function, which gives the remainder of division. You could look at each row number and if its MOD of 11 equals zero, then it's the row you're looking for.

I am counting 10 items in each section in your example so I'm not sure I completely understand. Let's assume you need to sum every row that ends in a 9 (A9, A19, A29, etc.). You can replace the 9's below with an 11.

`=ROW(A9)` gets you the row number.

`=MOD(ROW(A9),9)` gets  you a TRUE or false on weather that number is divisible by 9. If it is a multiple of 9, it will return the number 0.

Now use the SUM function and hit CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER to complete it. Note that the formula bar indicates that this is an array function by using curly braces. You don't need to type those in yourself.

`{=SUM(A1:A9*(MOD(ROW(A1:A9),9)=0))}`

Comment: No, I'm not getting your point, but it probably was my bad because I didn't explain clearly my problem. I have a table with towns and population divided in age classes; every town has 11 classes (0-9,10-19,20-29,30-39 and so on and so forth); I need to have the sum of the total population of each town in another column.